# what is the wrong in this PL/SQL block code?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have 3 tables in my db:

`manufacturer: IDm int primary key, 
              manufacturerName varchar.`

`car: IDc int primary key, 
     manufacturer foreign key references manufacturer(IDm).`

`rent: IDr int primary key, 
      car  foreign key references car(IDc).`

I want to create a procedure that prints out for each manufacturer : the number of cars that are made the manufacturer, and the number of the rented cars that are made by the manufacturer.

this is my code:

```
create or replace procedure Q8 as 
cursor c is select distinct manufacturername, IDm from manufacturer; 
cursor c2 is select * from car; 
rents int:=0; 
cars int; 
allrents int; 
p1 number(38,2); 
p2 number(38, 2); 
id int;  
begin 
   select count(IDr) into allrents from rent; 
   dbms_output.put_line('manufacturer cars rented cars % rents %'); 
   for k in c loop 
     select count(IDc) into cars from car c where c.manufacturer=k.IDm; 
     for k2 in c2 loop 
         select IDc into id from car where car.manufacturer=k.IDm;
         select count(car) into rents from rent r where r.car=id;
     end loop; 
     p1:=(rents/cars)*100; 
     p2:=(rents/allrents)*100; 
     dbms_output.put_line(k.manufacturerName||' '||cars||' '||p1||' '||p2); 
  end loop; 
end;
```

so, where is the wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean, what is wrong?   Does it run, but give wrong results?   Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Sparky , yes I got this result `ORA-01403: no data found`.

Comment: Well, the error message cannot be more specific.  One of your "select into" statements is returning no data.  Step through the code in the debugger, or print out your constraint values.

Comment: the problem is in this statment:
`select IDc into id from car where car.manufacturer=k.IDm;` , but it should return data.

Comment: And what is the value of k.IDm at the time that the `SELECT` statement fails? Perhaps you could put something like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('k.IDm=' || k.IDm);` right before the failing `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need cursors to achieve this

```
select manufacturername, IDm, count(cars.IDC) as CarsMade,
                              count(rent.car) as Rental,
                              count(rent.car)/count(cars.IDC) as p1,
                              count(rent.car)/xx.Tot as p2
from manufacturer m
join cars on cars.manufacturer=m.IDm;
join rent on rent.car=car.id
join (select count(*) as Tot from Rent) xx
```

See if that query gives you what you are looking for, it will run a lot faster than nested cursors

Comment: I want to make it by using cursors, its for learning purpose.

Comment: @user3194430, you can still make a cursor out of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to OldProgrammer - put an if before the second loop. 
If cars != 0 the do the second loop 
else rents will also be 0 and just set it so. 
You will also have to change your p1 statement as (0/0)*100 will throw a divide by zero error 
p2 will also and (0/allrents)*100 will always be 0.